# Combining oldSettings with newSettings

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

What's being done here is **combining** the **oldSettings**, with the **newSettings**.

**Code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/zt7anuL3/96/

The **oldSettings**, would be referring to the “**defaultSettings**,” what they all start off with.

```
 playerVars: {
            autoplay: 1,
            controls: 1,
            showinfo: 1,
            rel: 0,
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            cc_load_policy: 0,
            fs: 0,
            disablekb: 1,
        },
```

The **newSettings** would be, what gets specified in each **load player**.

```
loadPlayer({
    target: ".jacketc",
    width: 600,
    height: 338,
    start: 200,
    end: 205,
    loop:true
});
```

**I tried to do this on my own, but I'm not sure I wrote it correctly.**

I need to know if I'm doing this right or not, and if I'm not, what the correct way of doing it would be. If you could provide corrections to it that would be helpful.

Someone just told me I could use `Object.assign()` to combine properties, but how would this be done? And is that what I want to do here?

```
function combineSettings(oldSettings, newSettings) {
        const props = Object.keys(newSettings);
        const combinedSettings =  props.reduce(function combine(combined, prop) {
            if (typeof(oldSettings[prop]) === "object") {
                const oldProp = oldSettings[prop] || {};
                const newProp = newSettings[prop] || {};
                combined[prop] = combineSettings(oldProp, newProp);
            } else {
                combined[prop] = newSettings[prop];
            }
            return combined;
        }, oldSettings);

        return combinedSettings;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do what `Object.assign()` does.
You can use `Object.assign()` to combine properties of two or more objects.
You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

The important thing to remember is that the properties from preceding objects are overwritten by the objects that follow in the parameter list.

```js
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};

var obj2 = {
  a: 3,
  c: 4
};

var obj = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
console.log(obj);
```

You could modify your function as below:

```js
function combineSettings(oldSettings, newSettings) {
    return Object.assign({}, oldSettings, newSettings);
}
```

Comment: Did I do that right here, are there any corrections you would make in it? https://jsfiddle.net/zt7anuL3/96/ I need to know if I'm doing this right or not, and if I'm not, what the correct way of doing it would be. If you could provide corrections to it that would be helpful.

Comment: You suggested using Object.assign(), how would it be written using that?

Comment: Looks like your function works just fine but I just thought you might want to consider Object.assign() which does what you are trying to do. I will edit the answer to show how you can modify your function.

Comment: Can you also provide a jsfiddle of the code working using Object.assign()? That would be helpful so I can see. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would delete, remove this line: return combinedSettings;, and add this line instead? return Object.assign({}, oldSettings, newSettings); That's all I would do?

Comment: Wouldn't this line be written this way instead? return Object.assign(newSettings, oldSettings);

Comment: Yes, that will work too but using the syntax I wrote you have the added benefit of creating a new instance rather than mutating the oldSettings object. 
Also, looks like your playerVars property is an object as well. Object.assign() works only if you are trying to overwrite values for objects without arrays or objects (shallow merge). If you want the deep merge that copies sub-properties like playerVars as well I would look for deep merge implementations in libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#merge).

Comment: The code works properly when this is used: Object.assign(newSettings, oldSettings); / https://jsfiddle.net/zt7anuL3/99/ / The code you provided messes it up. return Object.assign(oldSettings, newSettings); https://jsfiddle.net/zt7anuL3/101/

Comment: Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/anything963/tqkhnfsp/3/):
Let me know if anything gets messed up as the videos seem to be playing fine.

Comment: After a button is clicked, it should start playing. autoplay=1 They don't start playing right away.

Comment: Also, none of the "defaultSettings" are enabled in your code. Which are the oldSettings. Only the newSettings are enabled in your code. Which are the settings inside the loadPlayer.

Comment: How would that be fixed?

Comment: What you are trying to do is deep merge whose implementation you can find readily but if you are feeling lazy [here](https://jsfiddle.net/anything963/tqkhnfsp/9/) a solution that will work for your case. I merged the playervars and re-assigned it after a shallow merge.
This will probably still not autoplay in jsFiddle but it seems to be auto playing when I run in html page.

Comment: Thank you, greatly appreciated. It does autoplay.

Comment: Can it be improved further than this? https://jsfiddle.net/g6oaht8f/28/ I took your solution and improved it. Can it be improved further though?

Comment: Indeed there is. Though the solution works for now, let's say in future, like playerVars you decide to add another property that stores settings as objects or arrays. You'll have to modify combineSettings function to accomodate for that. But if you want a solution that will work no matter what the settings object looks like you should look into how to do **deep merge**. A good place to start would be looking into how lodash library implements deep merge [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge).

Comment: What if I removed function combineSettings, and set it up this way instead? https://jsfiddle.net/g6oaht8f/113/ Is this a better way to do it?

Comment: No, I think what you had the last time is good. In this example you are merging settings to playerVars as well as oldSettings, which would make redundant properties in you result settings object.

Comment: Can you find anything wrong with setting it up like this? https://jsfiddle.net/g6oaht8f/158/ Is this a good way of doing it?

Comment: Are there any downsides to setting up the code this way? https://jsfiddle.net/g6oaht8f/158/